# Appending white spaces or truncating a string if string limit is exceeded in ksh

Tags: ksh

i have a string and i have to set the string size to 30 
IF THE STRING IS LESS THAN 30 , then we have to ad trailing spaces

ex :

```
 string="sai tejas"
```

output:

```
"sai tejas                     " Append White spaces
```

or if string exceeds string size (i.e 30) , then truncate the string , so that any time the size would be 30
ex:

```
 string="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl"
```

output:

```
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd
```

we are deleting any charecters after the limit is exceeded.

Below is the code that i have tried but i am unable to truncate the string and the whole string is being displayed

```
y="ssaiTejas11111111111111111111abcdefg"
printf "|%-30s|{1..40}\n" $y

   The above code prints the entire string , ideally it has to truncate abcdefg at the and
```

Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the string once it's been padded/truncated?  Are you looking to output the string in a fixed-width (30 char) format?  If we know how the string is to be used later then there may be some other ideas/options to consider.

Comment: I will save that in a text file , well the requirement is that it has to be 30 char , shorten it if it’s more or add spaces if less . We will save it in a txt file . But I see that this code is adding up spaces but the string size always varies , it’s not 30 constantly . Ex if input string is 15 char output is 24 , if it’s 18 output is some other number , but it’s never constantly 30 except of input is greater than 30

Comment: Did you look to all answers? Is one of them helping?

Comment: I have written a while loop which is working and I will post it

Answer (score 2):

The best way to be first create a source string containing full of spaces, 30 in your case and then append the source string as needed.

To create an empty string full of spaces, use the builtin `printf` tool as

```
printf -v fullOfSpaces ' %.0s' {1..30}
echo "${#fullOfSpaces}"
30
```

Now use parameter expansion to get the string

```
if (( ${#string} > 30 )); then 
    printf '%s' "${string:0:30}" 
else 
    printf '%s%s' "$string${fullOfSpaces:0:-${#string}}"
fi
```

If you check in either cases the resulting string length is 30.

The construct `${PARAMETER:OFFSET:LENGTH}` is a [Substring expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion) technique where we feed a length of the input string as the value, in which case the strings are counted from the end and the original source string takes the starting characters.

---

Some test results. Using `-v var` to store the resulting string out of `printf`

```
string='abcd'
if (( ${#string} > 30 )); then 
    printf -v new '%s' "${string:0:30}" 
else 
    printf -v new '%s%s' "$string${fullOfSpaces:0:-${#string}}"
fi

echo "${#new}"
30
```

For a longer string input

```
string="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl"
if (( ${#string} > 30 )); then 
    printf -v new '%s' "${string:0:30}" 
else 
    printf -v new '%s%s' "$string${fullOfSpaces:0:-${#string}}"
fi

echo "${#new}"
30
```

Comment: -vstrng.sh: bad substitution ,
i get this error, iam working on solaris box ,ksh actually

Comment: @Set a she-bang as `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top of the script and run it as `bash <scriptname>`

Comment: it works, but i would want that work for ksh as i have to add this in a huge ksh :)

Comment: @LearningCpp: Then remove `bash` from the title, it is no longer a bash question

Comment: hi, the else condition actually throws an error : -${#string}: substring expression < 0

Comment: @LearningCpp: What input are you passing to test that? It should hit the first if condition for that

Comment: @LearningCpp, please always add your os details in your posts.

Comment: iam just trying to use this bash script in my ksh script, but is it correct, can i use return function

Comment: @Inian : this bash script runs , but i am trying to call it from the ksh script and capture the string using return statement , but unable to use return statement in bash file, could you please help.                                             if (( ${#string} > 30 )); then
    #printf '%s\n' "${string:0:30}"
     return "${string:0:30}"

Comment: @LearningCpp: I tested the output before posting on `ksh`. It worked fine. What is not working?

Comment: Hi , I work on Solaris and it’s just random output and not 30 chars

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf for min and max length:

```
printf -v outputvar "%-30.30s" "${string}"
```

And when you do not know the required outputlength

```
len=30
printf -v outputvar "%-*.*sx\n" ${len} ${len} "${string}"
```

Answer (score 0):

create the variable as left justified with a length definition

```
$ typeset -L 30 y                         
$ y="sai tejas11111111111111111111abcdefg"
$ echo "|$y|"                             
|sai tejas11111111111111111111a|
$ y="sai tejas"                           
$ echo "|$y|"  
|sai tejas                     |
```

from `man ksh`

```
-L     Left justify and remove leading blanks from value. 
       If n is non-zero, it defines the width of the field,
       otherwise it is determined by the width of the value of first assignment.
       When the variable is assigned to, it is filled on the right with blanks
       or truncated, if necessary, to fit into the field.  The -R option is turned off.
```